# Root xml namespace getting wrongly mapped when escaping inner child nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, namespaces, escaping

I have an XML as below ,

```
<root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd">
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   <child xmlns="http://test.com">
       <element1>1</element1>
   </child>   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

And want the XML to be converted to

```
<root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd">
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   &lt;child xmlns="http://test.com"&gt;
       &lt;element1&gt;1&lt;/element1&gt;
   &lt;/child&gt;   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

Tried with the below XSL script using reference from another post in StackOverflow but it is not mapping correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*:root|*:parent|*:parentdtl|*:outer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the Mule ESB tool for this which uses the Saxon 9.6 version

The output received is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/rib/RibMessages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://mspdv170.us.oracle.com:7779/rib-func-artifact/integration/xsd/RibMessages.xsd
   <parent>test</parent>
   <parentdtl>
   &lt;child xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;
       &lt;element1&gt;1&lt;/element1&gt;
   &lt;/child&gt;   
   </parentdtl>
   <outer>T</outer>
</root>
```

The output contains the wrong namespace in the child escape node and in the root it is getting corrupted. Please share your thoughts if anyone has resolved a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in the root it is getting corrupted". Note that your posted XML has typos, for example a missing quote in the root start tag.

The reason that the serialized child element contains the namespace declaration for the `xsi` namespace is that the XDM data model treats all inherited namespaces as if they were declared locally on the element itself. If you want the serialized form to contain only the namespace bindings that are actually used on the element or on its attributes, try making a copy using `<xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no"/>` before you serialize, to eliminate the unwanted namespaces.

**UPDATE**

In your fiddle you are doing

```
<xsl:copy-of select ="@*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
<xsl:value-of select="serialize(., $ser-params)" />
```

so the serialize() isn't being applied to the copy, it is being applied to the original. You need something like

```
<xsl:variable name="copy-sans-namespaces" as="xs:element">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="serialize($copy-sans-namespaces, $ser-params)" />
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for noticing the typo, i have corrected it. I tried with the copy-of but it is not working , The root tag has different set of name space and one of the child node (<child> has different name space. Requirement is to retain the <Root> namespace as it is and also the namespace in the <child> node. The <child> node part has to be escaped along with its name space. I tried using the *: in my script but is not working as expected. Any pointers will be helpful further. Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to be more precise about exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. Probably best to raise it as a new question.

Comment: Hi Michael, i'm using the below tool to test, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/3 , hope you will be able to see what i'm trying to do. If still it is not clear I will raise it as a new question

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried using the above updated change in the fiddle but the transformation is not happening as expected and is same as before. please see this updated script in the fiddle , https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxN9PRK/4

Comment: This is a bug: see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4793.